# Automatically activate (focus) a program window upon opening

Tags: vlc-media-player

I hope I can explain this clearly. When I open a file (.mp3 in my case) that opens with the preferred program (VLC in my case), the program is not focused (greyed out, first screenshot) until I click on the window then it becomes focused (not greyed out, second screenshot). I want it to be focused without having to click on the program window upon initial opening. This will make my batch work much faster and less painful if I don't have to click every single time I open a file.

[image: Not focused]

[image: Focused]

Comment: Doesn't happen here. Probably some other program is stealing the focus. Can you see which one?

Comment: I close every other program. Still the same....

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Nothing seems to work. I tried putting "always on top" on VLC. Only sometimes it'll open an MP3 file and not be greyed. It's inconsistent. I even try restarting my computer. Same thing.

Comment: Strange behavior, so let's do general troubleshooting. I suggest checking the SMART data of the disks, run `chkdsk`, do [SFC & DISM](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html), and if nothing do [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: Uh, that's really too complicate for such a minor issue. I'm giving up hope here